# How do I get a list of recipients whose mailbox I have shared access to via Outlook Interop

Tags: interop, outlook

I'm trying to get some information on the recipients whose mailboxes I have shared access to. 
I know this can be found via OutlookSpy (IMAPISession -> OpenProfileSection -> 00020D0A-0000-0000-C000-00000000004 -> 0x0390), but I don't know where I can get this information via Outlook Interop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Outlookspy has the infomation you want then you can use the redemeption libs to get the mapi infomation you want in the same way. They a have a lib called [profman](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profiles.htm)

Comment: That library requires purchase for commercial applications.

Comment: What info do you need ? as I doubt you will be able to get this info from inside of OOM via a property accessor