# How to acquire all shared contacts with outlook interop?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I would like to acquire all contacts that are shared with the current Outlook user (= acquire all the folders containing contacts that are shared).
It's the kind of sharing where you receive an email invitation from the one who shares the contacts with you. You can then see the folder in your "Persons" tab. The folder is not visible in the "folders" view.

The following link shows a guide on how to reach my goal by enumerating the "nav links" in the elusive "common views" folder and then finally EWS folders via some arcane code.
Sadly, they are using EWS and not the OL interop I am bound to.
I thought I'd get started by acquiring the "Common Views" folder, but I am completely unable to do so. Recursively looking through olApplication.Session.Folders gives me my mailbox and the public folder and their subfolders, but no Common Views folder.

An answer to the following question could probably help me: [How do I get a list of recipients whose mailbox I have shared access to via Outlook Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162788/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-recipients-whose-mailbox-i-have-shared-access-to-via-outl)
I think I could call OpenShared(Default)Folder() with that information.

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: when you say the following `I think I could call OpenShared(Default)Folder() with that information` have you actually tried it..? or is it something in COM.Interop that you do not understand..? have you tried this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb610437(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Actually GetSharedDefaultFolder doesn't return a valid folder if I feed it with the recipient who is sharing his folder with me.